# How to receive a "DONE" TCP packet after waiting for server to finish processing

Tags: c++, tcp

I'm trying to get a couple Raspberry Pi's to network with one another to process data. After the client sends the server the initial config file, I'd like the server to send back a packet saying that it's done saving the config file to a file.

Originally, I had the server echo the message back and it ran just fine.

**client**

```
    // Initialize a connection to the server
    TCPSocket sock(
      config["server"].as<std::string>(),
      config["port"].as<unsigned short>()
    );
    // Send the configuration file to the server
    configRaw = "CONFIG\n" + getFileData(configFile);
    handleBuffer(configRaw, messageBuffer, messageLength);
    sock.send(messageBuffer, messageLength);
    while (totalBytesReceived < messageLength) {
      // When the bytesRecieved is negative, the packet received is no longer 
      // a part of the buffer. At this point the packet is no longer what the
      // server is sending back.
      if ((bytesReceived = (sock.recv(receiveBuffer, RCVBUFFERSIZE))) <= 0) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to read";
        exit(1);
      }
      totalBytesReceived += bytesReceived;
      receiveBuffer[bytesReceived] = '\0';
    }
```

**server**

```
  while(
    (messageLength = clientSocket->recv(messageBuffer, RCVBUFFERSIZE)) > 0
  ) {
    message.append(
      std::string(messageBuffer).substr(0, messageLength)
    );
    clientSocket->send(messageBuffer, messageLength);
  }
```

When the server only echos the original message, it runs fine. When I add an additional receive *while not changing the server*, the server never leaves its while loop:

**all of server**

```
  while(
    (messageLength = clientSocket->recv(messageBuffer, RCVBUFFERSIZE)) > 0
  ) {
    message.append(
      std::string(messageBuffer).substr(0, messageLength)
    );
    clientSocket->send(messageBuffer, messageLength);
  }
  std::istringstream iss(message);
  std::getline(iss, line);
  if (line == "CONFIG") { 
    writeConfigFile(message); // write the config file to disk
    handleBuffer(done, sendBuffer, messageLength);
    // Let the client know that the server has written everything to disk.
    clientSocket->send(sendBuffer, messageLength);
  }
```

**broken client**

```
    // Initialize a connection to the server
    TCPSocket sock(
      config["server"].as<std::string>(),
      config["port"].as<unsigned short>()
    );
    // Send the configuration file to the server
    configRaw = "CONFIG\n" + getFileData(configFile);
    handleBuffer(configRaw, messageBuffer, messageLength);
    sock.send(messageBuffer, messageLength);
    while (totalBytesReceived < messageLength) { // NEVER LEAVES THIS LOOP
      // When the bytesRecieved is negative, the packet received is no longer 
      // a part of the buffer. At this point the packet is no longer what the
      // server is sending back.
      if ((bytesReceived = (sock.recv(receiveBuffer, RCVBUFFERSIZE))) <= 0) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to read";
        exit(1);
      }
      totalBytesReceived += bytesReceived;
      receiveBuffer[bytesReceived] = '\0';
    }
    sock.recv(receiveBuffer, RCVBUFFERSIZE); // THIS BREAKS THE SERVER
```

Is there a certain order of operation when it comes to TCP sockets?

Comment: In the client if `messageBuffer` isn't null-terminated, `std::string(messageBuffer)` probably goes boom. Hard to be sure though

Comment: The `handleBuffer` function  ensures the messageBuffer is null-terminated. That was my problem the day before!

Comment: Without looking at your online code (which you shouldn’t ask people to do) - how does the server know when the client is done sending the file data, so it can then send a response? Are you sending the file’s size to the server? I’m guessing not. In your earlier code, we’re you closing the connection after sending the file? That would have acted like an end-of-file signal.

Comment: Originally, I was echoing the message sent to the server back to the client. With this, I was checking whether the `totalBytesReceived` was larger than the `messageLength` like it the code given. This works when echoing the code back in the while loop of the server.I just can't send any additional packets outside of the server's while loop. The server code won't leave the while loop if the client receives anything other than an echo. Is this a timing thing?

Comment: A "Done" TCP packet doesn't exist.

Comment: The “DONE” is given by `done` which is just a static string that is “DONE”